# using react-autosuggest with react-custom-scrollbars

Tags: reactjs

is it possible to use `react-custom-scrollbars` with `react-autosuggest` together?
I wrote this in for `auto-suggest` but it doesn't work correctly:

```
renderSuggestionsContainer({ containerProps, children, query }) {
    const callRef = scrollbars => {
        if (scrollbars !== null) {
            ref(scrollbars);
        }
    }

    return (
        <Scrollbars
        autoHeight
        autoHeightMax={240}
        id={this.props.id}
        ref={callRef}
        renderTrackVertical={() => <div className="scrollbars-wrapper" />}
        renderThumbVertical={() => <div className="scrollbar-handler" />}>
        {children}
        </Scrollbars>
    );
}
```

How?

Answer (score 0):

if want to implement react js auto-suggestion box, then you can simply use "**react-select**", have all feather like scrolling, loader etc.
 you will find more detail here https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select

if you want to implement your own with react-native
then instead of scrollbar you should use **ListView**, because it having more feather-like,

- Auto-caching image for ios and android,
- Method for onReachBottom which helps to implement infinite scroll. etc

Comment: Thanks RANVIR. `react-autosuggest` has scrolling, too. But I want to customize it. I choosed `react-custom-scrollbars` to do that but I cant configure them to work together.